# How to Create Prameters on CATIA V5 part

Tags: vb.net, catia

Could you please any one have idea about prameter creation using vb.net API of CATIA V5. If any one have idea about let me know using small samples code.

Thanks.

I want creat parameters between part models uaing vb.net. CATIA CUSTMIZATION USING VB.NET

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for the _parameters_-collection? (e.g. the method _CreateString_)

Answer (score 0):

I did not use VB.Net since a long time but bellow some samples.
As argument :
Name = Name of your parameter you want to create
Text = Text of value you want to assign (can be empty)

DotNet c#:

```
public static void addPropertyOnActiveDocument(string Name, string Text)
{
    Product product = null;
    if (Catia.ActiveDocument is ProductDocument productdocument)
    {
        product = productdocument.Product;
    }
    if (Catia.ActiveDocument is PartDocument partdocument)
    {
        product = partdocument.Product;
    }
    if (product != null)
    {
        product.UserRefProperties.CreateString(Name, Text);
    }
}
```

VB.Net:

```
Public Shared Sub AddPropertyOnActiveDocument(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Text As String)
    Dim product As Product = Nothing

    If TypeOf Catia.ActiveDocument Is ProductDocument Then
        product = DirectCast(Catia.ActiveDocument, ProductDocument).Product
    End If

    If TypeOf Catia.ActiveDocument Is PartDocument Then
        product = DirectCast(Catia.ActiveDocument, PartDocument).Product
    End If

    If product IsNot Nothing Then
        product.UserRefProperties.CreateString(Name, Text)
    End If
End Sub
```